# TFS: Enforce checkout of latest version for non-mergeable files

Tags: tfs, merge-conflict-resolution, getlatest

We have some files with binary content in our TFS repository. To avoid conflicts we already disabled the option "Enable file merging and multiple checkout" for those file types.

But we still run into problems when someone checks out an older than latest version of a file which results in a conflict when checking in.

Is there any setting to enforce get latest on checkout for specific file types?

Answer (score 0):

The commend way is to do a 'get latest' manually before the check out option.

You can also **Enable get latest on check-out box** in the Check-Out setting. Details you can refer [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242869.aspx). However, just enforcing for specific file types is impossible.

[image]

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately for code files it's the desired behavior, just for binaries it would be better the other way.